# Closing then opening browser with Watir

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, browser, watir

I want to close the current browser, open a new one and let it continue it's work.
It looks something like this:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
.....
browser = browser.close


browser = browser.new
..
```

But after closing the browser it returns

`uninitialized constant Browser (NameError)`

Thanks :)

Comment: Would you want to close your current browser which has been opened manually or through driver?

Comment: `browser = browser.new` doesn't look right, but I would expect a different exception than the one you showed. At any rate, you should be opening the second browser the same way you did the first one - ie `browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call browser.close, the browser object gets removed after the actual browser is closed.   To make a new one you need to use the same syntax you did the first time  (as indicated by Justin in the comments to your question)

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```